# auto-populate a column in a new row in edit list mode in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a list that is connected to a form and filtered based upon a value in the parent form (an ID field).  I want to allow the users to add new rows by directly editing the list.  In doing so, I don't want to have to make the users enter in the value that already exists on the form.  I can't seem to find anyway of doing this.

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjYTO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using infopath ? I think your option is to call a web service to verify such thing. Or if you customize your form using javascript you could achieve this the same way by javascript.

Comment: I did finally find something on code project that covers it for the most part.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/813090/Master-detail-with-JSGrid

It has a couple of problems with it, like field entries that disappear when you tab to the next cell but save and reappear when you go to the next row, and it doesn't run the JS when you click edit a second time (I took out the code that hides the hero links).